# When I import a Project in intellij there is error in the whole project

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, cucumber-jvm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55QUk.png)I am facing a issue in IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.2.4 x64 , is that when i import a project into my system there error in the pom.xml file as "Failed to read artifact descriptor" and also there is a error in step-definition also like in the import (Image is pinned)

NOTE: This problem arise only when i import a project , otherwise its working fine
      I have setup the environment for maven and java , and also i cleared cache and restart the intellij and I run the comment "mvn -U clean install" in my cmd and I set the auto update snapshots too in the intellij .

I am working with windows 7 .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NEAu.png)

Comment: Don’t post code as pictures. Copying text does not require more effort than creating screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

**Its because of win 7**

In win 7 sikuli 1.1.0 is not acceptable 
try sikuli 1.1.1 in pom.xml file